# Cannot connect to specific port from docker container to host machine on macOS

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to connect from the docker container to the host machine's port and it doesn't want to work for the specific port (in my case `9003`).

On the host machine, I checked that the port is open:

```bash
lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
```

and I see the target port (`9003`):

```
COMMAND     PID               USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
phpstorm  32838 mypersonalusername   17u  IPv4 0x0000000000000000      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:63342 (LISTEN)
phpstorm  32838 mypersonalusername  266u  IPv4 0x0000000000000000      0t0  TCP *:9003 (LISTEN)
```

And when I run inside the docker container the next command:

```bash
nc -vz host.docker.internal 9003
```

I see that this port is not available but when I try to reach another port:

```bash
nc -vz host.docker.internal 63342
```

and it works:

```
host.docker.internal (192.168.65.254:63342) open
```

I tried to use the `docker.for.mac.host.internal` host, I checked the macOS Firewall settings and even disabled the firewall but it didn't help. I see the difference in the port definition (`127.0.0.1:63342` vs `*:9003`) but I see no way to specify the host on the second one. Even with that, for some other applications, it doesn't matter and I can connect to ports with the `*` host (not for everything but still).

If it makes a difference I'm trying to establish an Xdebug connection from my container to PhpStorm.

I'm sure that only PHPStorm listens to the port, I tried to set a different one - the same result in the end. I don't expose the port from Docker. I know, the difference here. The issue is that Netcat returns no output and the exit code is `1` but it returns not immediately but it waits for something.

Could you please advise why it can happen and how to solve the issue?

Comment: *"I see the difference in the port definition (`127.0.0.1:63342` vs `*:9003`)"* That's fine. 63342 is for built-in web server/RPC and for security purposes it listens for local ( local host) interface only. While `*` listens on all interfaces so you can accept a debug connection from remote computer.

Comment: *"lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN"* is this the ONLY entry for `9003` port? They might be the only entries for PhpStorm process (considering that you showed those 2). But it is possible that another process also listens on TCP 9003 and connection simply does not reach PhpStorm. Double check that. People that do not know much about Docker/Xdebug or even networking in general often making a mistake by exposing Xdebug port in docker file/docker-compose config. Maybe you have that as well somehow (another container / previous experiment etc). Might be even another app (VS Code for example)...

Comment: You can also try the following: change Xdebug port to some another free number (e.g. `9005` or `9010`) . But do it in PhpStorm and PHP settings only (unless ofc you are passing Xdebug port via Docker config/env as well)...

Comment: @LazyOne yes, I'm 100% sure that only PHPStorm listens to the port and I don't expose it from the Docker. I tried to use different ports and the result is the same. The issue is that the Netcat returns the exit code `1` but not immediately, like it is waiting for something.

Comment: In such a case I do not know what else this might be. I'm not Mac user and not Docker expert. But the last idea for now: 1) does local connection works (netcat or telnet and connect to 127.0.0.1 on 9003 port? 2) will it work if you try the same from another device (another Mac/PC .. or remote server (via SSH tunnel etc). Basically --- to check if PhpStorm accepts connection on that port at all...

Comment: "But it is possible that another process also listens on TCP 9003" — no, that is not possible on Linux. A port can only be open in listening mode for one process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case, the VPN protocol blocked the connection. I don't know how and why and how to debug it but in the end, I changed the protocol and everything started working as a charm.

The only hint I got is to enable port listener from another application like:

```bash
nc -l 900
```

and see, that I couldn't connect here either.